# How to resize image into a header

Tags: css, image, header

[Current Navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsZCh.png)

Hi, I want to resize my image into the header, which is shown by the salmon background in the attached picture. For some reason, it doesn't fit but expands beyond it. I'm attaching the code below.

```css
body{
  background-color: bisque;
}
.header{
  background-color: salmon; 
}
.header img {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
 
}

.header h1 {
  top: 18px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel = "stylesheet" href="logo.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <img src="Small_scream.png">
    <h1>My website name</h1>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9340179/fluid-images-in-one-row

Comment: Really unconvential solution, but it def helps! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can position your image relative to the header size if you want to fit it inside the `header` div. And set the position of the image to `left` or `right` by changing these two property values.

CSS:

```
  body{
   background-color: bisque;
  }

.header{
  background-color: salmon; 
  position:relative;
}

 .header img {
  position: absolute;
  right:0%;
  width: 5%;
  height: 100%;
 }

  .header h1 {
   top: 18px;
   left: 10px;
  }
```

Also, you can fit the image in a more central position by:

```
img{
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

You can alter the object-position as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Set a height for your header - currently it's defined by your font size - and set your `img` height to 100%.

Comment: Perfect, Thank you!!